# How to hide data from a JSON response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this Javascript function that requests the information of a card based on its BIN (The first 6 digits).

```
const getCardInfo = async (cardNumber, isLive = false) => {
  const binCode = cardNumber.substring(0, 6);
  const cachedData = sessionStorage.getItem(`bin_${binCode}`);

  if (cachedData) {
    const jsonParsedData = JSON.parse(cachedData);
    const cardType = jsonParsedData.type === "CREDIT" ? "Crédito" : "Débito" ?? "Desconocido";
    const country = jsonParsedData.country || "Desconocido";
    const cardVendor = jsonParsedData.vendor || "Desconocido";
    
    let cardInfoText = '';
if (isLive) {
  cardInfoText = `LIVE [${cardVendor} - ${country} - ${cardType}]`;
} else {
  cardInfoText = `[${cardVendor} - ${country} - ${cardType}]`;
}

return cardInfoText;

  }
  else {
    const response = await fetch(`https://apilink.com/api/${binCode}`);
    const jsonParsedData = await response.json();
    if (!jsonParsedData.result) {
      return "DESCONOCIDO";
    }

    const cardType = jsonParsedData.data.type === "CREDIT" ? "Crédito" : "Débito" ?? "Desconocido";
    const country = jsonParsedData.data.country || "Desconocido";
    const cardVendor = jsonParsedData.data.vendor || "Desconocido";

    // Almacenar la información en la memoria caché solo si no existe previamente
    const cachedData = sessionStorage.getItem(`bin_${binCode}`);
    if (!cachedData) {
      sessionStorage.setItem(`bin_${binCode}`, JSON.stringify(jsonParsedData.data));
    }

    let cardInfoText = '';
    if (isLive) {
      cardInfoText = `- LIVE [${cardVendor} - ${country} - ${cardType}]`;
    } else {
      cardInfoText = `[${cardVendor} - ${country} - ${cardType}]`;
    }

    return cardInfoText;
  }
};
```

And it works fine, because I get in the Browser in Network>fetch/XHR section under "Preview" and "response" the following:

```
{"bin":542343,"vendor":"MASTERCARD","type":"CREDIT","level":"STANDARD","bank":"BANCA COMERCIALA CARPATICA S.A.","country":"ROMANIA","countryInfo":{"name":"Romania","emoji":"","unicode":"U+1F1F7 U+1F1F4","code":"RO"}}}
```

But I want that instead of showing all that, just show `cardNumber - LIVE` (card number is the card number that is in other functions etc).

How can I do it? I don't have much experience.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can't stop the Network tab displaying the JSON results

That is outside your control as a programmer. If you want the end-user to not be able to see it in the console, you must get the server to not send it to you.

However, it is probably not worth your while to put major effort into this, because your code will be *sending* the BIN code.

Since your Javascript "knows" the BIN code, always assume that anyone can compromise your Javascript to reveal the BIN code.

Even if you decide to encrypt the BIN code (and can modify the `//apilink.com...` code to accept this encrypted code, along with not echoing it in the response), you should remember that the Javascript can be easily modified by a malicious user to store a copy of the original unencrypted BIN code.

Comment: How I can encrypt the request?